# Session management in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, flask

I want to manage a session using a flask. My project is deployed on the cloud. So the problem which I am facing is that, as the user variable gets updated whenever a new user logged in to the site. So the previous user variable gets changed.

I am fetching username and password from the login panel and store it into the `session['user'] = form.username.data` and retrieving it by `return render_template('addcourse.html', user=session['user'])`

But the issue is the same. What to do. Can I use flask's build in `from flask import LoginManager` module to do that? And if so then help me out in that also.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of session - server side stored session and client side stored session.

Flask use client side session by default (without 3rd party or your own extensions), so actually session in Flask is data extracted from cookie file.

Cookie files are stored in user's browser when user open some link the cookie file is send to server, server read the file and change (if need) data in cookie and send it back to client, then browser rewrite the cookie file for the website.

So another user (another browser) can not change any data if another user PC or just browser in the same PC (cookie file belong to browser and dedicated to website).

So, you have to check logic of your code.